# Datatables - export to Excel only selected option in select when column number may change

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

i working with export tables to excel with Datatables plugin.
We have custom forms of tables - the client himself chooses how many columns he needs and what columns they will be - it can be a drop-down list, checkbox or input. Therefore, the number and position of the columns changes every time.
I am trying to export only the selected value in a dropdown list. How can I do this? I saw an answer when they indicate a certain column and look for a drop-down value in it, but this option does not suit me, since each client has a different number of columns and a different position always

Here is an HTML(I can't change it because the table is formed in PHP and the client himself decides what size table he needs)

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="studentsTable" class="table table-small-font table-records dataTable no-footer" style="margin-top: 15px" role="grid">
    <thead class="text-uppercase" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <tbody id="students">  
        <tr id="tr_17529" role="row" class="odd">
            <td>
                <a href="#" onclick="openStudentModal(870); return false">Абдуллина Марина</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="phone">+79111467738</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form class="custom-fields-form" id="event_modal_cf_form_22_3881">
                   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="BZ9c3F344ObmgruzG04bqkD3szyl2xXt1xa6Uxeg">
                   <input type="hidden" name="field_id" value="22">
                   <input type="hidden" name="model_type" value="student_to_events_group">
                   <input type="hidden" name="model_id" value="3881">
                   <select class="form-control-xs" name="custom_fields[22]" onchange="saveCustomFieldModelValue(22, 3881);">
                      <option value="">Не выбрано</option>
                      <option value="1">Вариант1</option>
                      <option value="2">Вариант2</option>
                      <option value="3">Вариант3</option>
                    </select>         
                </form>
             </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Also Datatables export preferences:

```
$('#studentsTable.table-records').DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "searching": false,
        'info': false,
        "sort": false,
        dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
        buttons: [
            {extend: 'copy'},
            {extend: 'csv'},
            {extend: 'excel', title: 'Список учеников',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 1, 2 ]}
            },
            {extend: 'pdf', title: 'Список учеников',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 1, 2 ]}},
            {extend: 'print',
                customize: function (win){
                    $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                    $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                    $(win.document.body).find('table')
                        .addClass('compact')
                        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                }
            }
        ],
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "pageLength": 25,
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you can achieve that with external button that runs this script like:
var tableTr  =   $('tbody>tr[role="row"]');
for(var i = 0; i < tableTr.length; i++){
//find the value you need
}